# specifying alternate `id` when using `withRelated` in Bookshelf.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, orm, bookshelf.js, knex.js

I'm curious if there is a way to change the `id` used when specifying `withRelated` on a model?

Here's the situation:

I'm working on a platform that has a calendar component and that calendar needs to support recurring appointments. Rather than creating every potential instance of a recurring appointment, I'm generating these recurrences on the fly, which leads to much less maintenance going forward. My `Appointment` model also has relations that are associated with each instance. An `Appointment` can have many `services`, etc. When loading these relations using `withRelated` on an appointment that exists in the database (is not dynamically generated), the `id` of that appointment is passed into whatever relation `withRelated` attempt to load and works great.

However, with these dynamically generated appointments, I actually need to load the relations using the `id` of the parent appointment from which these instances were generated. Unfortunately, I can't seem to find a way to either specify to use that parent `id` or a place where I can intercept and change it before the relation is loaded.

My situation is an odd one, but it would be a simple fix if I could change what is passed in when `withRelated` is called.

Is this possible?

I'm also open to other suggestions.

## Goal/Desired Results

Just to be clear, my goal is fairly simple. When Bookshelf loads a many-to-many relationship, it uses the `idAttribute` of the joining model in order to load related relations.

For example, `Appointment` is my primary model and has a many-to-many relationship with `Pets`. Therefore, when I load the `pets` relation, Bookshelf does a join on the `appointment_pets` table looking for all records where `appointment_pet.appointment_id IN (?)` where the parameters are `id`s from the `appointment` table.

My desired goal is to be able to substitute `appointment.id` with `appointment.parent_id` when looking up these relations as in my situation, these dynamic records don't actually exist in the database yet and therefore need to use the information attached to the parent record, which does exist.

## Updates

I was finally able to get different `id`s injected into the above query by temporarily changing the `idAttribute` on the model from `id` to `parent_id`. The query is correct and parameters being passed are also correct, but the relationships are empty when the model is returned.

```
// appointment model

    pets() {

        return this.belongsToMany('Pet', 'appointment_pet', 'parent_id');
    },
},

// Returns all appointments
    fetchAll(businessId, options) {

        options = options || {};

        // If a start and end date are passed, return all appointments
        // within that range, with recurrences expanded.
        if (!_.isUndefined(options.startDate) &&
            !_.isUndefined(options.endDate)) {

            const startDate = Moment(options.startDate);
            const endDate = Moment(options.endDate);
           
            // temporarily change id attribute so `parent_id` is used when looking up the relation
            Appointment.prototype.idAttribute = 'parent_id';

            return Appointment
                .query((qb) => {

                    qb.from(Bookshelf.knex.raw('get_appointments(?, ?, ?) AS appointment', [businessId, startDate.toISOString(), endDate.toISOString()]));
                })
                .fetchAll({
                    withRelated: [{
                        pets: (qb) => {
                            qb.select(['appointment_id as parent_id', 'pet.*']);
                        }
                    }]
                });
        }

        // Otherwise, return all appointments
        return Appointment.findAll({ businessId: businessId }, options);
    },
```

I see the following debug output:

```
{ method: 'select',
  options: {},
  bindings:
   [ null,
     '35a2941c-d73f-4cf3-87de-bfbcbc92fbc5', <-- these are all `appointment.parent_id`
     '5de28a57-ce4c-4fcc-865a-54cf97e08c6c',
     'bf4b6784-b96a-4321-8335-e449aa8dcda1',
     '695edc54-3a93-42a5-a3e0-b331f26912cf',
     '76a99204-9659-4270-904c-2c42e5c40a15',
     '28437e3c-abc1-4fd6-8c26-5543c09ab730',
     '350da29d-0e82-4e6c-b9fe-be31c64655b4',
     'bcaee041-c9ec-4a34-8c0d-8f21d2d79197',
     '91380fcc-2f0d-4344-a24b-dc37abe3931f',
     '31796797-5041-4fae-815b-0f2c368654b0',
     '94800af3-fd23-4b59-af88-15b1f622e8e1',
     'aa8c202d-249e-4ffc-ab55-e535f2c2121f',
     '8a1fd093-45a6-4864-8c52-ea8851740f77',
     '5f91ad6f-4231-4d18-b718-d99fcc17a18b',
     '5f879e43-a44f-41dd-b9dd-11f06af4cc8d' ],
  sql: 'select "pet".*, "appointment_pet"."parent_id" as "_pivot_parent_id", "appointment_pet"."pet_id" as "_pivot_pet_id" from "pet" inner join "appointment_pet" on "appointment_pet"."pet_id" = "pet"."id" where "appointment_pet"."parent_id" in (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)'}
```

Running this command in postgres, I see the correct output, but still no relations. I saw #1203 and tried adding the `parent_id` explicitly to the select, but still no luck.

Comment: Can you provide any code, ie database schema, current models, data, desired result SQL that would provide your desired results etc? The more the easier it will be to provide a solution

Comment: @uglycode: just updated with some additional information. Appreciate the help! This is a real doozy. I could jump down to the Knex level and do this all manually, but the change needed to make this work seems so simple that I shouldn't need to re-invent the wheel for something Bookshelf already does.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately I don't have enough data to replicate your problem. I tried it on a basic one-to-many example, and I think the easiest way is to define a new relation in the model itself. E.g.:

```
var Genre = bookshelf.Model.extend({
    tableName: 'genres',
    movie: function() {
        return this.hasMany(Movie);
    },
    movie_parent: function() {
        return this.hasMany(Movie, 'parent_id');
    }
});

var Movie = bookshelf.Model.extend({
    tableName: 'movies'
    genre: function() {
        return this.belongsTo(Genre);
    },  
    genre_parent: function() {
        return this.belongsTo(Genre, 'id');
    }

});
```

So then, you can query it reasonably simple, in the `withRelated` property.

```
new Movie().fetchAll({
    withRelated: ['genre_parent'] //can be replaced with withRelated: ['genre']
}).then(function(movies) {
    res.json(movies);

});
```

If this is not the solution you're looking for, please provide additional data (database structure would be interesting to see)